# WooCommerce, sell by weight and by units

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to create a grocery store to sell meat and vegetables using the WooCommerce plugin.

My client wants that the visitors would be able to buy products by units (e.g 5 tomatoes) or by weight (e.g 1.5 KG of tomatoes).
It should be applied for all the products or most of them.

I am using the extension [Measurement Price Calculator](https://woocommerce.com/products/measurement-price-calculator/) and it works fine cause I achieve to have a "weight" field where customers can enter an amount and it is converted into money.

But I can't find a way to have both options at the same time, weight field and unit field!

It’s possible to do it with the WooCommerce?
How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a support issue.  Why don't you ask the plugin author, rather than posting here?

Comment: Cause they are in vacation...

Comment: WooCommerce is a multi-million company.  I don't think "they are in vacation".

Comment: I can guarantee you. 
I can't paste here the screenshot but:
"The entire Automattic Family, including us here at Woo, will be attending our Annual Grand Meetup where we’ll be working to improve our systems and processes to better serve you. We won’t be available to respond to support requests during this time, but we look forward to helping you when we return on September 22, 2016.

Please refer to the links below for product setup and general troubleshooting."

Comment: Ok, the've replied to me. It's not possible to achieve. It need some custom code.